# Difference in between widget and portlet in Yii

Tags: php, yii, diff

I am new to Yii framework, and just came across widget & portlet.

Can anyone please differentiate all these theoretically as well as practically also.

Answer (score 4):

In Yii1 portlet is specific widget. CPortlet class actually extend CWidget (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/zii/widgets/CPortlet.php). From Yii web site:

> CPortlet is the base class for portlet widgets. A portlet displays a
>   fragment of content, usually in terms of a block on the side bars of a
>   Web page.

(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPortlet).

In comparison Widgets are more general. From Yii forum topic:

> Portlet is a Widget with some additional attributes. If you don't > need them (title, hideOnEmpty, css...), then use a widget ...

(http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12128-yii-widget-vs-yii-portlet/).

So, CPortlet is extension from CWidget with some common functionality designed to use on specific part of page (like for example box of 'see also' links, or 'similar articles' or anything like that what usually have 'title' and 'body').

Comment: Nice answer, but please take the time to format your answer, like I did for you.